OpenRC not starting services
For testing purposes, I need a quick way to generate a root filesystem to use for booting freshly built Linux kernels. I've been doing this by using Docker to create a filesystem and then transferring this into a CPIO archive for use as an initrd. The process looks something like:
docker build -t rootfs .

fakeroot bash <<'EOF'
rootfs=$(mktemp -d rootfsXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf "$rootfs"' exit

docker container create --name "rootfs-exporter" rootfs
docker container export "rootfs-exporter" | tar -C "$rootfs" -xf-
docker container rm -f "rootfs-exporter"
tar -C "./rootfs.template" -cf- . | tar -C "$rootfs" -xf-

mkdir -p boot
(
cd "$rootfs"
find . -print0 | cpio -0 -o -H newc
) | gzip > boot/initrd
EOF

Where the Dockerfile used to generate the filesystem is:
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
  apk add bash ax25-tools ax25-apps iproute2 net-tools \
  vim procps curl tmux openssh openrc socat netcat-openbsd

RUN bash <<EOF
rc-update add sshd default
EOF

COPY etc/ /etc/
COPY init /init

Because we're booting an initrd we need a /init, which looks like this:
#!/bin/sh

mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
mkdir /dev/pts
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
exec /sbin/init

And finally, /etc/inittab (which is read by busybox init) looks like:
ttyS0::sysinit:/sbin/openrc sysinit
ttyS0::sysinit:/sbin/openrc boot
ttyS0::wait:/sbin/openrc default
tty1::respawn:/bin/bash

I can then boot a kernel and this filesystem using qemu like this:
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 1g \
      -kernel "path/to/bzImage" \
      -append "hostname=linux console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 rw" \
      -initrd "boot/initrd"

And it works, sort of. The system boots  up, I get a shell on the console, ssh is running...but it looks like none of the openrc sysinit scripts (like localmount) are running. At first I figured this was because I hadn't explicitly enabled the service, so I added rc-update add localmount to the image generator. On boot, we can see the localmount is now enabled:
linux:/# rc-update show
           localmount |                                 sysinit
                 sshd |      default

But it didn't start:
linux:/# rc-service localmount status
 * status: stopped
linux:/# ls /sys
linux:/#

If I run it by hand it works as expected:
linux:/# rc-service localmount start
 * Mounting local filesystems ... [ ok ]
linux:/# ls /sys
block     class     devices   fs        module
bus       dev       firmware  kernel

What's missing here? Why are services not running -- even when enabled -- unless I explicitly start them from the command line?
